# Is multiplication for A^n matrix commutative and does it follow the law of exponents?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How to prove (or disprove) that when given $A$ as a square matrix and $n$ as a positive integer,

$A^n = A^{n-1}A = A^{n-2}A^2 = \space ... \space =A^2A^{n-2}= AA^{n-1}$

I have checked up to the fourth power and the statement holds true.

Comment: Hint: Matrix multiplication is associative: $A(BC)=(AB)C$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you want to prove $A^n=A^k\cdot A^{n-k}$ for some $k\leq n$.

Note that, by definition of matrix multiplication,
\begin{align}
A^n&=AAAA\dots n\text{ times}\\
&=\left(AAAA\dots k\text{ times}\right)\cdot \left(AAAA\dots (n-k)\text{ times}\right)\\
&=A^k\cdot A^{n-k}
\end{align}

This holds for any arbitrary $k$.

This completes the proof.

Comment: But matrix multiplication isn't commutative. Why is the order irrelevant in this case?

Comment: @Mick_Mick Surely $A$ commutes with itself. In other words $A\cdot A= A\cdot A$ where the two $A$s traded places! Non-commutativity does effect things. For example, it may happen that $(AB)^2\neq A^2B^2$ or $(A+B)^2\neq A^2+2AB+B^2$. But for example the binomial formula holds whenever the two matrices commute. So we always have $$(I+A)^3=I+3A+3A^2+A^3$$ because $I\cdot A=A\cdot I$ for all $A$.

Comment: @Jyrki Oh. That's right. At first, I looked at it like $A^2$ has no proof of commuting with $A$. But I forgot that it actually came from squaring $A$ in the first place. I am quite dumb lol.

Comment: @Mick_Mick Not dumb as you saw what's going on. On a first course on abstract algebra you will see the associative law come into play on more occasions. Now you will be better prepared for that course in comparison to class mates who did not stop to think about this! It was easy for me because I have played with these things a lot.